# In MySQL 8.x the string function FROM_BASE64(str) returns result in hexadecimal form instead of a string

Tags: mysql, binary, base64, hex, string-function

I have the following queries -

```
SELECT "Abc" AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| Abc    |
+--------+

SELECT TO_BASE64("Abc") AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| QWJj   |
+--------+

SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc")) AS result;
+----------------+
| result         |
+----------------+
| 0x416263       |
+----------------+
```

[--binary-as-hex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex) page in mysql dev site says -

> To disable hexadecimal notation, use `--skip-binary-as-hex`

I tried the following but got error -

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc")) --skip-binary-as-hex AS result;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as-hex AS result' at line 1
mysql> SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc") --skip-binary-as-hex)  AS result;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as-hex)  AS result' at line 1
mysql> SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc" --skip-binary-as-hex))  AS result;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as-hex))  AS result' at line 1
```

In the same page they have said how can I use the `USING utf8mb4` clause to get the result in case of `CHAR()` and `CONVERT()` functions but they have not stated anything about `FROM_BASE64()` function. Nevertheless, I tried it and got error -

```
SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc") USING utf8mb4) AS result;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING utf8mb4) AS result' at line 1
```

I tried the `UNHEX()` function -

```
ELECT UNHEX(FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc"))) AS result;
+----------------+
| result         |
+----------------+
| 0x0ABC         |
+----------------+
```

Clearly this is not the desired result as well as all are in capital. Here `LCASE()` wouldn't work as well as it will turn every word to lower case.

Even, this result is not in string as is evident from -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UNHEX(FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc"))) FROM 4) AS result;
+----------------+
| result         |
+----------------+
| 0x             |
+----------------+
```

So the only option seems to be to disable `-binary-as-hex`

But I can't find out a way to do this.

Here as similar question is there in stackoverflow -

['FROM_BASE64' Function Returns Hex Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099436/from-base64-function-returns-hex-value)

But it is on MySQL Version 5.6.14. I am using MySQL Version 8.0.27 -

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

So my case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --skip-binary-as-hex option is to be used as an option to the mysql command when you open that from a shell prompt. It's not an option to be used within SQL syntax. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_binary-as-hex

That said, you can convert binary to strings even if binary-as-hex is enabled:

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc")) AS result;
+----------------+
| result         |
+----------------+
| 0x416263       |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64("Abc")) USING utf8mb4) AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| Abc    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You may need to use a different character encoding. Mine is utf8mb4, but yours may be different.

Comment: Thank you, really easy solution and I even knew it, somehow it missed my mind, don't know why.